# How to use computedFrom with multiple properties in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have the following code:

```
@computedFrom(['id', 'isDiscontinued'])
get disableAdd(){
    return this.id === '0' || this.isDiscontinued;
}
```

This throws the following error: aurelia-binding.js:2580 Uncaught TypeError: this.input.charCodeAt is not a function

This however works:

```
@computedFrom('id')
get disableAdd(){
    return this.id === '0' || this.isDiscontinued;
}
```

But I need two computedFrom fields, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@computedFrom('id', 'isDiscontinued')
get disableAdd(){
    return this.id === '0' || this.isDiscontinued;
}
```

Didn't need `[]`